# How to define a yield function on nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use yield keyword to deal with async calls in my nodejs application. Below is my code:

```
class InspectorController {
  function* foo(){

  }
}
```

when I run the code nodejs gives me an error on the function declaration as below:

```
function* foo(){
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Comment: Method declarations have the form `*foo() {}`, not `function *foo() {}`. Please revisit the class syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to use Generator in a ES6 class

```
class InspectorController {
  * foo(){
    // Do something
  }
}
```